# Gimp copy and paste in text editor

Tags: gimp, text

Hi I'm trying to add lots of names to a design that are repeated. for instance.

first last. first last . first last . Etc.

I only have about 20 names but need to fill a large area so was hoping to repeat the names . in gimp text editor I can't seem to copy and paste or use a plain text doc to copy and paste into the text editor. any help would be amazing

Comment: Select the text in your text document, and copy it. Back in GIMP, select the Text tool. Click on the image where you want to add the text, and hit Ctrl+V to paste.

Answer (score 0):

In the Text Tool's options, there is a checkbox marked  `Use Editor`: that will activate the legacy separated-window dialog for entering text.

While in less convenient than writing directly on the canvas, it may be more useful sometimes. In this case, it will use more regular handling of copy/paste functions, as provided by the GTK +2.x toolkit, and may attend you.

Comment: The default Text tool behaviour, i.e. typing directly on the canvas, works perfectly fine with copy and paste.

Comment: Not _all_ pastes: while the OP here is likely on Windows and it is all the same to him, Linux users have two distinct clipboards: one regular with ctrl+c, ctrl+v and another that uses only mouse-highlight + middle-click.  The standard editing mode won't paste with middle-click.

Comment: That's sounds more of an operating system issue rather than anything to do with GIMP per se.  Remember that GIMP is mutli-platform, so its copy and paste behaviour might be a bit of a compromise - i.e. not fully supportive of just one particular operating system, but rather an approach which will more or less work on all three operating systems (Mac/Win/Linux).